# Remap right Windows key to Alt Gr?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 23.04

[image: Image of keyboard]

EDIT:  This is Ubuntu 23.04 x64 in the default Ubuntu flavor.

I have upgraded my ancient Model M keyboard to a modern one where Windows keys have been added.  Being Danish we use the Alt-Gr key a lot which has been shifted one key to the right and a Windows key is now where my muscle memory goes.

I would like to remap the right Windows key to Alt-Gr (and leave the left Windows key as is.  The output from `xev` when pressing and releasing the keys is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x49d, subw 0x0, time 18696093, (125,74), root:(2722,175),
    state 0x10, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x49d, subw 0x0, time 18696725, (125,74), root:(2722,175),
    state 0x50, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x49d, subw 0x0, time 18697421, (125,74), root:(2722,175),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x49d, subw 0x0, time 18698721, (125,74), root:(2722,175),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What is the best way to do this remapping?  Can the Ubuntu tools help edo this, or do I need to do some low level X11 magic?

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of the version/Distro of Ubuntu in use.

Comment: Some low level X11 mapping may not work if you run Wayland (the default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the **Alternate Characters Key** control in *Settings -> Keyboard* is for.

Disable the *Use layout default* switch and select **Right Super**.

Comment: This made my right Windows key get the Alt-GR functionality (but the Alt-Gr key lost it).  This is not very well explained in the Settings program, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user18619318: Any idea how it could be explained better?

Comment: Explicitly mentioning that this is the Alt-Gr behavior would have been helpful.

Comment: @user18619318: Note that the key is named "Right Alt" on some keyboards While the <AltGr> /<Right Alt> key is used by default as the key for accessing 3rd and 4th level symbols, "the AltGr behavior" wouldn't describe the control very accurately.

Comment: I would suggest that mentioning in passing the information you just stated there, would help others like me to actually understand what the help text is helping with.

Comment: @user18619318: Currently it says: "The alternate characters key can be used to enter additional characters. These are sometimes printed as a third-option on your keyboard." Would you like to see an elaboration of that info?

Comment: Yes.  "third-option" only makes sense if you know what it is already.   "These are sometimes printed as a third-option on your keyboard, frequently Alt-Gr." would probably be sufficient.

Comment: @user18619318: I see the point, and I'll make a mental note about it for now. It's a bit complex, because that section is from GNOME, but Ubuntu applies a couple of patches which need to be taken into consideration.